# My Jframe Freezes When I start a process

Tags: java, jframe, processbuilder

i build a process for run an exe file from java app so run with start() then my frame freezes. It's just becoming a picture. I can't even close it with X. When i minimize the frame and open it again i see darkness in frame. My threads running in background, i can see from output but why my frame freezes?

Comment: Threads blocking a queue that dispatching events to other components. It could be a deadlocking issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i build a process for run an exe file from java app so run with start() then my frame freezes

Probably because you start the process on the Event Dispatch Thread and the process is blocking the Thread which means the GUI can't respond to events or repaint itself.

The process should be started in a separate Thread. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.

Comment: The process starting was in event  dispatch thread. So i started it in a thread then i checked is it still in EDT with javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread(), it returns false now. But my problem isn't solved. What i have to do?

Comment: Something is blocking the EDT. I can't debug your code for you. I can only point you in the direction for you do to the debugging

Comment: I found it, that was a while in a infinity loop in EDT. Now it's solved. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide some code, the problem could be a number of issues so it would help cut down on some of them.

I would suggest checking that you haven't suspended/slept any of your threads.

Comment: The code is too complicated, too many classes and connected to each other. So i wanna try to explain: i got frame and 5-6 classes which extends threads and in a while(true) loop. The threads are listening web service methods. If i take video call request it shows up on a new frame and i accept it and disposing new frame. Before disposing the button listener of new frame building process and starts it. So my videochat.exe runs and mother frame freezes. I tried to dispose mother frame and create it when videochat.exe closed, it still freezes. Then I tried invokelater, this time never shows up.